# slices in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, slice

Is there a faster / more "pythonic" way to access the values associated to a single key in a list of dictionaries other than looping over it (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940442))? I am looking for something like `listDict[:]['id']` to get the list of valules, but I get the error `list indices must be integers, not str`, even though `listDict[0]['id']` works just fine.

Update - followup question:
What if the value for the key is also a list itself and I'm only interested in getting the first 10 elements of it?

When using list comprehension it's easy to do `[dic['id'][:10] for dic in listDict]`, but what about when using `itemgetter`? `map(itemgetter('id')[:10], listDict)` doesn't seem to work.

I'm asking about a fast way to get access because I have a huge list of dictionaries and I thought that I can get the same behaviour as numpy arrays (like slices being only views of the original array) for lists of dictionaries. I'm wondering if python has any way of exploiting the fact that all dictionaries in my list have the same size for using fast strided memory access and copying large chunks of data at a time without making intermediate representations as a list of lists.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but this is a duplicate of the linked question you gave, all the same answers are there

Comment: I was aware of the answers given to that question and I am interested if there are any _other_ alternatives.

Comment: The most pythonic and fastest solution is the accepted answer there

Comment: I end up making a numpy array from this, but I don't know whether to preallocate it and loop through the dictionaries and copy the data to the corresponding row, or use list comprehension and `numpy.asarray()`.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't do slicing like that here. You've loop through the whole list and fetch items from each dict.

Use a list comprehension:

```
[dic['id'] for dic in listDict]
```

or `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('id'), listDict)
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> listDict = [{'id':1,'other':2},{'id':3,'other':4},{'id':5,'other':6}] *100

>>> %timeit [dic['id'] for dic in listDict]
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.8 us per loop
>>> %timeit map(itemgetter('id'), listDict)
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.7 us per loop

>>> listDict = [{'id':1,'other':2},{'id':3,'other':4},{'id':5,'other':6}]*1000

>>> %timeit [dic['id'] for dic in listDict]
1000 loops, best of 3: 446 us per loop
>>> %timeit map(itemgetter('id'), listDict)
1000 loops, best of 3: 440 us per loop

>>> listDict = [{'id':1,'other':2},{'id':3,'other':4},{'id':5,'other':6}] *10**5

>>> %timeit [dic['id'] for dic in listDict]
10 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit map(itemgetter('id'), listDict)
10 loops, best of 3: 45.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: `map` `itemgetter` is slower and uglier than your first given solution

Comment: @jamylak It turned out to be faster.

Comment: Not on tiny lists, and the difference is negligible